# How can I make my login page authenticate correctly in laravel

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-4

I have a login form in the root url in my system. ie when I load the following url

```
http://localhost/mysite/public
```

It loads my login form whose form element looks like this.

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/mysite/public" accept-charset="UTF-8" />
```

I have setup my routes as follows

```
<?php
/**
 * Route to login page
 */
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('login');
});

/**
 * Route to validate login details
 */
Route::post('/', 'LoginController@postLogin');
```

and I have my `LoginController.php` like this.

```
class LoginController extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * Use to validate login authentication
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function postLogin()
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(array('username'=>Input::get('usename'), 'password'=>Input::get('password')))) {
            return Redirect::to('dashboard')->with('message', 'You are now logged in!');
        } else {
            return Redirect::to('/')
                ->with('message', 'Your username/password combination was incorrect')
                ->withInput();
        }
    }

}
```

My problem is, when I submit my login form, it is not invoking `postLogin()` method. This is because my form action does not contain a trailing `index.php`. When I add this to the url, it triggers `postLogin()` function. But in that case, when user login fails, it redirects to `http://localhost/mysite/public/index.php` which is not I needed.

What I need is, I want to make the form get validated when the form url looks like `http://localhost/mysite/public` and it should always redirect to the same url without having `index.php`.

What should I do in this case. I know I have to do something with `.htaccess`. But nothing is working for me.

Below I am providing my `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @AnandPatel : i will work on this from a windows system and also from lamp. Currently I am working on a lamp system. I want a solution which should work both in windows and lamp

Comment: dont know about lamp stack but on windows(WAMP) you need to enable mod_rewrite extension

Comment: also make sure your server is pointing to the public folder of laravel and get rid of that /public in your url